# Can the b value in an equation of a hyperbola be 0?

Tags: conic-sections

My teacher asked us to comment on possible values of the numerical eccentricity of hyperbolas. I came to a conclusion, and also saw online, that the value range of ɛ is ⟨1, +inf].

`ɛ = √(a² + b²) / a`

For `ɛ < 1`, b² would have to `b² < 0` which is impossible with real values of b. When `b² > 0` ɛ is `ɛ > 1`. However, when `b² = 0` ɛ is `ɛ = 1`, but is that even a hyperbola then?

Comment: What happens to the equation $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1$ if you set $b=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eccentricity characterises a conic section the following way:

- A circle has eccentricity $0$
- An ellipse has eccentricity between $0$ and $1$
- A parabola has eccentricity $1$
- A hyperbola has eccentricity strictly greater than $1$

Geometrically, conic sections are, well, cross sections of a cone. And the eccentricity is the ratio between the sine of the slope of the intersecting plane with the sine of the slope of the cone, assuming the cone has a vertical axis (and horizontal is angle $0^\circ$).

If you're using your formula with semi-major and semi-minor axes, then for an ellipse, the formula for eccentricity is almost the same, except you *subtract* $a^2-b^2$ in the square root.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. Still isn't intuitive to me, but I get what you're saying. Many thanks!

Comment: Thought about the ratios of sine of angles for a moment, now I understand it intuitively, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the cone planar intersection curve a hyperbola, then the least value admissible for eccentricity is 1. This happens when cutting plane is parallel to a cone generator.

$\varepsilon =0 $ is a circle, not even a parabola... much less a hyperbola.